# How can I hide and make visible JTable in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

What I did when I loaded the form I set the jscrollpane to invisible:

```
jScrollPane1.setVisible(false);
```

It worked well but when I tried to make it visible (naturally `jScrollPane1.setVisible(true);`) then nothing happens and it does not become visible.

What do I miss?

Comment: 1) after changing its visibility, you need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container that holds it. OR consider using a CardLayout to swap views.

Answer (score -1):

In your JFrame (I'm assuming you're using a JFrame to hold the scrollpane), call these two functions:

`getContentPane().validate();
 getContentPane().repaint();`

immediately after you set the scrollpane to visible

Comment: Thank you guys very much. That was a lifesaving. And a very annoying thing that I did not know :) But thx again